# C#: How to force a full load of users using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, delta

Is there a way to control whether a full load delta or an incremental load delta is processed for an Azure Function?

I'm grabbing user info from Azure AD using Microsoft Graph API and the code I have executes an incremental load since the last load executed.

I want to be able to execute a full load of the Azure AD users without needing to purge/delete the relevant storage account, especially in a Production scenario. The relevant code follows:

```
public async Task<GraphUserProcessorResult> CheckUserDelta(DeltaBuilder deltaBuilder, ILogger logger)
    {
        List<User> gUsers = new List<User>();
        var index = 1;
        var userPg = await GetNewPgUser(deltaBuilder, logger);
        gUsers.AddRange(usersPg.Where(IsRelevantUser));
        while (usersPg.NextPageRequest != null)
        {
            index++;
            usersPg = await usersPg.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
        }
        GraphUserProcessorResult gUserResult;
        logger.LogInformation("Found in graph " + gUsers.Count + " after " + index + " requests");
        index = 0;
        foreach (var gUser in gUsers)
        {
            index++;
            if (index >= 10) { break; }
        }

        if (userPg.AdditionalData != null && usersPage.AdditionalData.TryGetValue("@odata.deltaLink", out object deltaLink))
        {
            gUserResult = new GraphUserProcessorResult(new DeltaBuilder(deltaLink as string, userPg), gUsers);
        }
        else
        {
            gUserResult = new GraphUserProcessorResult(null, gUsers);
            logger.LogWarning("No Delta Link Found");
        }

        return gUserResult;
    }

 private async Task<IUserDeltaCollectionPage> GetNewPgUser(DeltaBuilder deltaBuilder, ILogger logger)
    {
        var lastPg = deltaBuilder?.lastPg;
        var deltaLink = deltaBuilder?.deltaLink;
        var retriesLeft = 5;
        ServiceException lastException = null;
        while (--retriesLeft > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                if (lastPage != null && deltaLink != null)
                {
                    return await _gUserClient.GetNextUserPage(lastPage, deltaLink)
                        .ConfigureAwait(true); // mute warning
                }
                else
                {
                    return await _graphUserClient.GetNewUserDelta()
                        .ConfigureAwait(true); // mute warning
                }
            }
            catch (ServiceException e)
            {
                // blah
            }
        }

        logger.LogError("blah");
        throw lastException;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the official Microsoft Graph document: [Get incremental changes for users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-users).

This delta endpoint is designed to obtain changes to users **without having to fetch the entire set of users from Microsoft Graph and compare changes**.

There is not an endpoint which allows you to execute a full load delta of the Azure AD users. The only workaround is fetching the entire set of users and compare changes by yourself as the document mentioned.